# Apply Changes on Parent Iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have an Iframe something like this.

```
<iframe id="test" src="test.html">

</iframe>
```

In my `test.html` I want to add a script to change width and height of iframe.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#test').attr("width", "510px");
   });
</script>
```

But its not working.

Comment: `css`... `$('#test').css("width", "510px");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this `inside` the iframe html page.

**Width:**

```
<script>
    window.parent.document.getElementById("test").width = 900;
</script>
```

**Height:**

```
<script>
    window.parent.document.getElementById("test").height = 900;
</script>
```

Comment: showing this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: This error seems to happen on Chrome, but it works fine in Firefox.

Comment: oh yes.. but any solution for all browser?

Comment: Oh yes - sorry, are you trying to run the `.html` in the browser locally? (`file:///C:/your-file.html`). What you need to do is setup a webserver, like WAMP and then run the page on `localhost` in the browser. As `file:\\` in the browser has different security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the IFrame you can resize the IFrame with this snippet:

```
<script>
    parent.document.getElementById('test').style.width = "510px";
</script>
```

Just be careful, when you get into IFrames you'll run into browser security sandboxing, which could cause troubles interacting with content inside the iframe from outside of it or vice versa.

Comment: Message Showing : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me in Chromium. Are your two pages on the same domain, and are you using file paths or a web server? If you're on a Mac or Linux system you can typically run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` to get a simple web server running on the current directory.